# NullPointerException when calling service in onResume 

Tags: android, service, binding

I am attempting to make a call to a service, and based on the response, redirect the user to a different activity (a login).

If I wait to do this until say, a button click, then it works fine (since the service is bound), but if I do it onResume, then I get the following exception:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {...MyActivity}: 
        java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and my code is:

```
FooService fooService;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FooService.class);
    bindService(intent, fooServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
   //I would assume the service would have bound by now?
   super.onResume();
   doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What makes you think that `fooService` exists at the point of `onResume()`?

The call to `bindService()` is asynchronous. It will happen when it happens. You cannot `doSomething()` until `onServiceConnected()` is called, and `onServiceConnected()` may not have been called by the time `onResume()` is called.

And, if `get()` on `fooService` is doing network I/O, you need to rewrite your app to move that off the main application thread and onto a background thread.

Comment: @UBM: If you come from a Javascript background, perhaps PhoneGap will be a better choice for you. "It is doing network I/O... can you provide some resources that can help me do that?" -- here is an `IntentService` that receives a command to download the file, then downloads it and lets the activity know of the results when the download is complete: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/Downloader "if I depend on the service, how can I make a call to it when it is ready?" -- call it from `onServiceConnected()`.